# Can't subscribe to local mosquitto broker

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I have a python code that publishes value on an mqtt brocker.
I do not receive any vslues when I connect to my local mosquitto while it's running fine when I use *broker.hivemq.com*

The code to sender code is

```
import time
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from random import randrange, uniform

mqttBroker ="broker.hivemq.com" 
#mqttBroker ="mybroker" 

client = mqtt.Client("publisher")
client.connect(mqttBroker) 

for i in range(3):
    randNumber = uniform(20.0, 21.0)
    client.publish("mytopic", randNumber)
    print("published " + str(randNumber) + " to topic mytopic")
    time.sleep(1)
```

and to subscribe, I use

```
mosquitto_sub -h broker.hivemq.com -t mytopic
```

which works fine

If I uncomment `#mqttBroker ="mybroker"` and then use `mosquitto_sub -h mybroker -t mytopic`, then nothing is received

mosquitto.conf file is

```
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log
allow_anonymous true
```

and it is running in docker on raspberry pi

```
docker run -it --init --restart=always --name mosquitto -p 1883:1883 -v $(pwd)/mosquitto:/mosquitto/ eclipse-mosquitto
```

Any help is welcome

Comment: add `listener 1883` to your `mosquitto.conf` file

Comment: Works perfectly. Many thanks !